# How to convert this to using Futures, not sure how to use Future.Traverse

Tags: scala, future

I have the following old code that was previously NOT returning futures, but it is now:

```
for (rg <- effectedRoleGroups) {
        val pm = securityService.generateABC(rg.id)
        redisService.setABC(rg.id, pm)
      }
```

Now both securityService and redisService are returning Futures.

I know I can do this:

```
for {
result <- Future.traverse(effectedRoleGroups)(rg -> securityService.generateABC(rg.id)
}
```

But I am not sure how I would use the result in this case to pass to my other service.

Comment: What's actually effectedRoleGroups?

Comment: please clarify if you want *your* function to return a future or if you want it to wait for the results of the functions it calls and return a regular value.

Comment: I want it to be non-blocking.  I want to somehow perform the operation I was doing originally in my ```for (rg <- effectedRoleGroups) ...``` statement, but now my services are returning futures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you want to ignore result of Futures as you use foreach loop you can do this like this:

```
for (rg <- effectedRoleGroups) {
  for {
    pm <- securityService.generateABC(rg.id)
    _ <- redisService.setABC(rg.id, pm)
  } yield ()
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for (rg <- effectedRoleGroups) {
  securityService.generateABC(rg.id).flatMap(pm => redisService.setABC(rg.id, pm))
}
```

Using `Future.traverse`:

```
val results: Future[List[ResultFromRedis]]] = Future.traverse(effectedRoleGroups)(rg => 
  securityService.generateABC(rg.id).flatMap(pm => redisService.setABC(rg.id, pm)))
```

This will give you `Future` of `List` of results that `redisService.setABC` will yield.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  But in your first snippet, you don't have a yield in the for-comp, I have to return something right?  I get a compile error if I don't put a e.g. Unit

Answer (score 0):

```
Future.traverse(..some traversable..)(...)
```

returns Future of transformed traversable. 
So you actually don't need to use *for* here. Instead you can do:

```
 val resultFuture = Future.traverse(effectedRoleGroups)(rg -> securityService.generateABC(rg.id))
```

If you still want to use *for* you need *yield* operator:

```
val resultFuture = for {
  result <- Future.traverse(effectedRoleGroups)(rg -> securityService.generateABC(rg.id))
} yield result
```

Comment: But how do I use the result to pass to redisServie.setABC(rg.id, pm) ?